# Enabling Sprite Kit Multiple Touch

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

I can't seem to enable multiple touch on the SKScene.

I've tried:

```
self.view.multipleTouchEnabled = YES;
self.inputView.multipleTouchEnabled = YES;
```

but still `touchesBegan:` only gets one touch. Is there some trick I'm missing?

This is how I'm checking the touches:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
  NSLog(@"Touch outside loop");
  int i = 0;
  for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
    NSLog(@"Touch count inside: %i",++i);
  }
}
```

This is the output. Always without exception:

```
Touch outside loop
Touch count inside: 1
```

Then I have to lift my finger and touch again as it won't register another touch until I do. Again getting:

```
Touch outside loop
Touch count inside: 1
```

Comment: Multi-touch is enabled by default. To access multiple touches, loop over the elements of the `touches` in `touchesBegan`.

Comment: Weird. I'm doing that and it's only registering one click. I have to lift my finger and touch the screen to get another touch. Updating my question with what I'm seeing.

Comment: Try calling `[super touchesBegan...]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS tracks each touch event throughout its lifecycle. In other words, when the user touches the screen, a touch object is created and passed to `touchesBegan`. If the user's finger moves, the object is updated with the new touch location and passed to `touchesMoved`. When the user's finger is no longer touching the screen, the object is passed to `touchesEnded`.

The following demonstrates one way to implement multi-touch in SpriteKit. Since multiple touches are involved, this code must be tested on an actual iOS device.

First, create and add sprites to the scene (for testing purposes).

```
- (void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {    
    for (int i=-2;i<3;i++) {
        SKSpriteNode *sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Spaceship"];
        [sprite setScale:0.25];
        sprite.position = CGPointMake(0, i * 75);
        [self addChild:sprite];
    }
}
```

Next, use the touch's previous location to determine which sprite is being dragged and move the sprite to the touch's current location. By looping over the touch events in the `touches`, we can move multiple sprites at the same time with different fingers.

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
        CGPoint previousLocation = [touch previousLocationInNode:self];
        SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:previousLocation];
        if (node != self) {
            node.position = location;
        }
    }
}
```